# Disable Button Click after clicking

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am uploading large file to Amazon S3 with Progress Bar, I am displaying Jquery progress bar, following [This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/uploading-file-with-progress-bar/)
Every thing is working fine, but there are two problems
If during processing user Select another file or Click Upload button multiple times, the progress bar count get increased
I have disabled FileUpload Control on button upload click event, but its not disabling the button upload control

This is How I am doing:

```
protected void btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (FileVideoUpload.HasFile)
  {
       FileVideoUpload.Enabled = false;
       btnupload.Enabled = false;
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);
       //Upload File on Amazon S3
       lblmsg.Text = "Video uploaded Successfully";
       FileVideoUpload.Enabled = true;
       btnupload.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```

I also tried this,but still button is not disabling

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnupload.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnupload, null) + ";");
}
```

Also I have tried disabling it in JS.
I want to disable both controls while processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can disable it on click event

```
 $('#btnupload').on('click',function(){
        $(this).prop('disabled','disabled');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but still its not disabling it :(

Comment: Same issue, Can you suggest some real time processing while file uploading?

Answer (score 1):

Try this with Jquery :-

```
$('#FormId').one('submit', function() {
$(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
 // find input type submit button or any other buttons which u want //
});
```

Comment: Thanks, after this code, Progress bar is hiding immediately

Comment: Plz post ur jquery code how u r showing progress bar???...becoz my ans should work fine..

Answer (score 1):

try this if `#btnupload` is in fact the button that you want to be clicked and disabled. I didn't quiet get that.

```
$('#btnupload').on('click',function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
```

and later for enabling it again use:

```
$('#btnupload').prop('disabled',false);
```